# How to read xlsx file in Apache POI in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apache-poi, xlsx

I am trying to read xls and xlsx files. able to read xls but for xlsx 
getting Exception:-

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventFactory;
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.PackagePropertiesMarshaller.<clinit>(PackagePropertiesMarshaller.java:45)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:161)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.<init>(OPCPackage.java:141)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.<init>(Package.java:37)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:87)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:272)
        at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:258)
```

in "**Workbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileStream);**" this line.

Apache POI jar files:-

poi-3.11-20141221.jar

poi-ooxml-3.11.jar

poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11.jar

poi-scratchpad-3.11-20141221.jar

xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar

also add

stax-api-1.0.1.jar

but not able to build this jar file in Android Studio.

i am not getting how to do this.

Comment: Does your version of Android provide the `javax.xml` XML parsing library?

Answer (score 1):

Try running without stax-api. Using stax-api.jar is not helpful in poi > 3.9 and may cause conflict if you are using Java 6 or above.  As per Apache poi components [page](https://poi.apache.org/overview.html)

> The OOXML jars require a stax implementation, but now that Apache POI
>   requires Java 6, that dependency is provided by the JRE and no
>   additional stax jars are required. The OOXML jars used to require
>   DOM4J, but the code has now been changed to use JAXP and no additional
>   dom4j jars are required.

Comment: As far as I see there seems no problem with the jars. you should probably check your build configuration and try. Also use xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar for this version.

Answer (score 0):

Add following dependencies in your code.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
```

To write on excel file there are two options:

1. To write in .xls file.

   ```
    Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("My Sheet");
    Row row= sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
   ```
2. To write in .xlsx file

   ```
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("My Sheet");
    Row row= sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
   ```

To read from excel(.xls/.xlsx) file:

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
```